# Why do all angular component test examples show an inefficient way of running component tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

All the tests in the docs have the testbed being reconfigured before each and every test executes. Surely the below is must more efficient and will mean tests run considerably faster.

*for some reason beforeAll to setup testbed and beforeEach to create fixture doesnt work due to a zone error, but nested describe pattern works.*

```
describe('The shared form component:', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormComponent>;
    let component: FormComponent;
    let httpClient: HttpClient;
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

    // setup testbed before all tests run to improve tests speed
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                SharedTestModule,
                FormsModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
            ],
            declarations: [
                DateFieldsInputComponent,
                PasswordValidatorDirective,
                FormComponent,
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ApiBaseService, useValue: {} }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();

        httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
        httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    }));

    describe('A basic form with text input fields', () => {

        beforeEach(async(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
        }));

        afterEach(() => {
            // After every test, assert that there are no more pending requests.
            httpTestingController.verify();
        });

        it('should create the component', () => {
            expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Because tests are isolated, and by creating a single testbed, you're making them run on the same platform. Say your first test changes a boolean, and the second test checks the boolean value : the second test depends on the first one, while they should be unrelated. 

I agree it isn't the best way to unit test, but it's the only way to test the template intercations. Also, it's their framework, so if they advise one way of testing, they probably have reasons to (especially after all these years of trials and errors)

Comment: The thing is though using the above I configure the module once, I will use spies to mock the providers so there wont be state elsewhere and my nested beforeEach recreates the component ensuring no state bleed over from there either. It runs much quicker.

Comment: if your only issue is with performance, just remove the testbed ans treat your component as a basic class.

Comment: Otherwise, again, it's just best practices, they don't force you to use their syntax. Feel free to try yours, but again, be careful, as you will encounter side effects.